# Restrict a folder access in Apache runtime APR

Tags: apache, tomcat

I have a folder structure like abc/xyz123/123,abc/asd/123,abc/xyz123/123.
           My apcahe runtime(APR) is configured to serve anything inside abc, but I want to restrict it for xyz... folder only and serve else as before.More clearly any folder whose name starts with xyz and it is inside abc folder(which has all permissions).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to not show indexes?

Open tomcat-apache.conf

Add

```
<Directory "/abc/xyz">
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

This will stop people from going to yoursite.com/abc/xyz and getting a directory structure. They would however be able to access yoursite.com/abc/xyz/image.jpg

If you want to block all access
Add this to the conf file

```
<Directory "/abc/xyz">
    deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/abc/xyz/123">
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.2-doc/tomcat-apache-howto.html - shows more details

Comment: In what way do you want to restrict those folders? Ans)I have a folder name in my url. Whick will occur at particular location only in URL(i.e. at particular pattern).Like abc/xyz/fileName.html, Can I get more help or example or reference.

Comment: What do you mean by apache runtime. Do you mean "Apache Portable Runtime" (APR) or apache webserver. If you're not sure tell me what OS you have and how you installed it.

Comment: Its Appache Portable Runtime

Comment: I am aware of apache, and there it is as,  <Directory "D:/Arun/abc/xyz">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>, similar configuration is required in APR?

Comment: Can we also restrict folder whose name has a pattern like always starting from abcd, in same above scenario?